# Sync LDAP groups and UIDs with Active Directory

Tags: ldap, synchronization, active-directory, uid, gid

Currently, our organization has a working OpenLDAP server that we use to login to our Linux environments. However, due to the increase in Windows devices, the higher-ups have decided to migrate to an AD-focused environment. We are currently trying to set it up and running into issues with GIDs and UIDs.

We do not want our users to lose access to their files and would prefer to touch the linux servers as little as possible. I have connected test servers to AD successfully via Centrify Express, but I can't seem to find a way to sync the LDAP UIDs and GIDs. Are there any options short of migrating every file for every user to the new UID?

This would only matter for existing users as new users could just be created in AD.

Comment: Roughly how many LDAP-based Linux servers need to be migrated, and how many users of those systems? Tens of servers and the easiest solution night well be to write a script that migrates UIDs and GIDs

Comment: @roaima We only have about 1000 users so scripting is definitely an option. Was just hoping there was another option